# Why does tmap not produce earth shaped/round plots with tmap_style("natural") anymore?

Tags: r, tmap

When I'm using the tmap style "natural" or "classic" the map is not earth shaped anymore. I am using the same code that created the earth shaped plots. I tried

- closing all packages
- restarting R
- `dev.off()`
- setting all options manually instead of using `tmap_style("natural")`

Do you have any ideas where this comes from? Thank you in advance :)

Here is a minimal example:

```
# libraries
library(tmap)

# data
data("World")

tmap_style("natural")

tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons("HPI", legend.title = "Happy Planet Index")
```